# How to make pre-depends install packages in debian packaging

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I am building a package that depends on package X, Y, Z. So i put them into the `control` file und der

`Pre-Depends: X, Y, Z`

However, this doesn't install the packages it just says my package can't be installed before these weren't installed. How do I make the package install the other packages automatically?

Or is `Pre-Depends` the wrong place to look at?

Answer (score 2):

Pre-depends works, however you need to install your package with `aptitude`/`apt-get` or `gdebi`, which are able to resolve dependencies, `dpkg` alone cannot do it.

```
$ gdebi your-package.deb
```

Comment: do you have a reference link for this claim?  I'm having the same issue and would like to read more about it from the docs.  Thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/dpkg , `dpkg checks dependencies and will refuse to install a package whose dependencies aren't met, but it won't help you find and install those dependencies. You need a higher-level tool (e.g. aptitude, apt-get or dselect) for that.`